HTML-5 form attribute with class instead of id
I am making two separate forms, and would like them to be both linked to the same button. In HTML5, one can link the submit button outside of a form with only an id. Is there any way to include a class, or at least the same id to the parent button?
EDIT: I am NOT submitting any data, only validating if the checkboxes are checked. If a person tries to move onto the next page by clicking the submit button, they have to first tick all the checkboxes. I am working with a disclaimer that needs to be clicked, and nothing more.
Main parent button
<button form="checkedTrue" type="submit">Submit example</button>

Form1:
<form id= 'checkedTrue'>
    Checkbox: <input type='checkbox' id='myCheck' name='test' required>
</form>

Form 2:
<form id= 'checkedTrue'>
    Checkbox: <input type='checkbox' id='myCheck2' name='test2' required>
</form>


If you link the submit button to multiple forms, which one is it supposed to submit? You can only submit one form at a time.

This question is similar to: Submit two forms with one button. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I am trying to validate the checkboxes as required. The button is more of a link to the other page. To put it simply, one cannot go onto the next page unless all checkboxes are ticked

@JohnLyons How do you validate it? Via JS? You don't need any form element to have working input fields and control then via JS

Why do they have to be in two different forms?

If they're on separate parts of the page, you can use the form attribute in the checkboxes to make them part of the same form.

I have a disclaimer checkbox that is not within reach of main  field, and am using the "required" function on the input forms for validation. As mentioned, I just need to ensure that the checkboxes were clicked.

in HTML 5 you can simply attach any forms elements to your form,
by the use of form attribute.


myForm.onsubmit = e => 
  {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  console.clear();
  console.log('cbx1 = ', myForm.cbx1.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked' );
  console.log('cbx2 = ', myForm.cbx2.checked ? 'checked' : 'unchecked' );
  }
<form id="myForm"></form>
 
<p>Checkbox1:<input type="checkbox" name="cbx1" form="myForm" ></p>
<p>Checkbox2:<input type="checkbox" name="cbx2" form="myForm" ></p>

<button type="submit"  form="myForm" >Submit button</button>



